# can not change data in the @change vuejs handler

Tags: javascript, input, vue.js, onchange

There is a component that contains *input[type=file]*.
Also, this field has an *uploadFile* handler, which calls the *validateMessage* method, which attempts to change the error. As you can see, after changing this.error it shows that everything is correct. But in div.error it is not displayed and if you look in vueDevtool, then there is also empty.
[data in vueDevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ5E7.png)

```js
data() {
  return {
   error: ''
  }
},
   
methods: {

 validateFile(file) {
   if (! file.type.includes('video/')) {
     this.error = 'wrong format';
     console.log(this.error); // wrong format
   }
 },
 
 uploadFile(e) {
   const file = e.target.files[0];
   this.validateFile(file);
 },
}
```

```html
<input type="file" 
       id="im_video" 
       name="im_video" 
       @change="uploadFile"
       class="hidden">
           
<div class="error">
  {{ error }}
</div>
```

Comment: i'm not 100% sure what is the problem. is the `console.log` line called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working example.

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data() {
    return {
     error: ''
    }
  },

  methods: {

   validateFile(file) {
      console.log(file.type);
     if (! file.type.includes('video/')) {
       this.error = 'wrong format';
       //console.log(this.error); // wrong format
     }
   },

   uploadFile(e) {
     this.error = '';
     const file = e.target.files[0];
     this.validateFile(file);
   },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" 
         id="im_video" 
         name="im_video" 
         @change="uploadFile"
         class="hidden">

  <div class="error">
    {{ error }}
  </div>
</div>
```

If you are using component this would help more to share data from child to parent in your case setting `error` from child component to parent

```js
Vue.component('upload-file',{
  template:`<div><input type="file" 
         id="im_video" 
         name="im_video" 
         @change="uploadFile"
         class="hidden"></div>`,
  data() {
    return {
     error: ''
    }
  },

  methods: {
   validateFile(file) {
      //
     if (! file.type.includes('video/')) {
       vm.$emit('filerror', 'wrong format');
     }
   },

   uploadFile(e) {
    vm.$emit('filerror', '');
     const file = e.target.files[0];
     this.validateFile(file);
   },
  }
});
const vm = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  mounted(){
    this.$on('filerror', function (msg) {
      this.error = msg;
    })
  },
  data:{
    error:''
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <upload-file></upload-file>
  <div class="error">
    {{ error }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is in inattention .. I forgot that there are several components in it and in vueDevtools like in DOM I looked into another component. Thank you for your time and I'm sorry I wasted it.