# How to get dinamically changed array from one component to another component in VUE js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a problem with getting data from component 'Overview.vue' and show in to component 'TopNavbar.vue'

The user has sections and can add some of them like Favorites, you can see it in picture below.

In 'Overview' component i have a method which push objects into array , this array is stored into data.user - object.

```
data () {
  return {
      user:{
       ..........................objects-objects
      'userConf': [],
      'email': 'Benno.Jaborek@abprod.dvag.de',
      'status': 'OK'
    },
  }
},
methods: {
  addToFavorites: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var getHref = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.href
    var getName = event.target.parentElement.children[1].innerText
    var isExist = (this.user.userConf).some(function (el) {
      return el.name === getName
    })
    if (!isExist) {
      this.user.userConf.push({name: getName, link: getHref})
    }
    console.log(this.user.userConf)
  },
```

When i loop through userConf array , i can see changes in this component , but when i try to computed/watch from component 'TopNavbar' , the data doesn't change.

```
<li v-for="fav in this.getAddedFavorites">
    <a :href="fav.link">
      {{ fav.name }}
    </a>
 </li>

<script>

  import Overview from 'src/components/Dashboard/Views/Dashboard/Overview.vue'
  export default {
    components: {
      Overview
    },
    data () {
      return {
        getAddedFavorites: Overview.data().user.userConf,
        activeNotifications: false
      }
    },
    computed: {
      getEl: function () {
        console.log(this.getAddedFavorites)
        // shows empty Array
      }
    },
```

[vue-dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE0xv.png)

I will be glad if someone can help me because I have been struggling with this problem for the second day :)

Comment: Are you using `vuex`? Another solution is using Event Bus. Access `Overview.data().user.userConf` is not a right way to do

Comment: Use `$on` and `$emit` to pass data from child to parent, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50618405/2815635)

Comment: A little advice, you might want to use a new array reference with `array = [...array, newItem]` instead of `push` a new one. To avoid inconsistency within your application. It's (pretty much) always better to consider your variable as an Immutable object. To answer your question, if you're not using Vuex, use events bult-in Vue to update parent component properties.

Comment: No , i don't work with vuex. I find solution , when the both components aren't with relation Parent/Child. I created a new .js file with :                                                                                                      const Favs = {
  data: [],
  methods: {
    add (item) {
      Favs.data.push(item)
    }
  }
}
export default Favs                                                                               which hold data and after that i can send info between components.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answers, because all three answers help to solve the problem :)